# django filter choices, order choices on template in order written in filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a Django Filter that that has 4 choices. I would like to order these choices on the template in the order that I have written them in the filter.

**filter.py:**

```py
RarityChoices = {
  ('common', 'Common'),
  ('uncommon', 'Uncommon'),
  ('rare', 'Rare'),
  ('mythic', 'Mythic')
}

rarity  = ChoiceFilter(field_name='rarity', empty_label='Any', choices=sorted(RarityChoices), widget=RadioSelect())
```

**template.html:**

```html
<div>
  <label class="mb-1" for="id_type">Rarity:</label>
  {{ card_filter.form.rarity}}
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

If I change my filter to:

```py
rarity  = ChoiceFilter(field_name='rarity', empty_label='Any', choices=RarityChoices, widget=RadioSelect())
```

The filter looks like this on the template:

[image]

Neither are in the order that I want or in the order listed in the `filter.py` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RarityChoices = {
  ('common', 'Common'),
  ('uncommon', 'Uncommon'),
  ('rare', 'Rare'),
  ('mythic', 'Mythic')
}
```

is a set ... sets are unordered ... change it to a list or a tuple

```
RarityChoices = [  # [ is for list
  ('common', 'Common'),
  ('uncommon', 'Uncommon'),
  ('rare', 'Rare'),
  ('mythic', 'Mythic')
]
```